# Find in nested arrays mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Below the data structure of my services in MongoDB:

```
"serviceInfo" : {
    "title" : "Lorem ipsum",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "availabilities" : [ 
                {
                    "businessDay" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "name" : "Monday"
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Now, I want to query all the services available the Monday during the period between `startDate` and `endDate`.

I tried this code but I have an empty array as result instead of my document.

```
db.collection('services').find({
  'serviceInfo.options': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'startDate': { $lte: new Date(req.query.date) },
      'endDate': { $gte: new Date(req.query.date) },
      'availabilities': {
        $elemMatch: {
          'businessDay.id': req.query.day
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).toArray()
```

I guess my problem is in the nested array `availabilities` but I don't find the correct way to do the query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you have correct inputs ? This should be `'startDate': { $gte: new Date(req.query.date) },
      'endDate': { $lte: new Date(req.query.date) },` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

`'businessDay.id'` expected an Int32 and parseInt(req.query.day) did the trick.